# Sylvester's theorem: gaining and losing a change in sign

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading Whittaker's *Analytical Dynamics.* My question is about Sylvester's theorem:

> Let $a_{ij}$ and $b_{kl}$ are two real, symmetric, $n\times n$ matrixes and $a_{ij}$ defines a positive definite quadratic form $\sum a_{ij}x_ix_j$. Then the determinant equation $\det(a_{ij}\lambda-b_{ij})=0$ has only real roots.

This theorem is given in the chapter on oscillatory movements. The proof goes as follows:

> Let $\det(a_{ij}\lambda-b_{ij})=\Delta$. Let $\Delta_i$ be the determinant of the same matrix but without the first $i$ rows and columns. ($\Delta_n=1$)...
>
> ...Here's why as $\lambda$ grows from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ these functions lose $n$ changes in sign.
>
> But as $\Delta_n$ is non-zero, and $\Delta_{r-1}$ and $\Delta_{r+1}$ have opposite signs whenever $\Delta_r=0$, the functions $\Delta,\dots,\Delta_n$ may not lose or gain change in sign...

What does Whittaker mean by losing or gaining a change of sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure (specially without seeing the whole proof) of what Whittaker meant "loose $n$ changes in sign". However, in case its of any use, here's another way to look at it.

What you're calling Sylvester's Theorem (as far as I can tell there's a whole bunch of results that are often referred to as Sylvester's Theorem) is simply the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and $A$ is positive definite, then the solutions to the generalized eigenvalue problem

$$\lambda A v = Bv$$

are real (the roots of $\det(\lambda A -B)=0$ are the $\lambda$'s that satisfy the above for some $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$). Since $A$ is positive definite we can re-write $A$ as its Cholesky decomposition $LL^T$ where $L$ is lower triangular with positive numbers on its diagonal (thus, it's invertible). So,

$$\lambda A v = Bv\Rightarrow \lambda LL^Tv=Bv\Rightarrow \lambda L^Tv=(L^{-1}B(L^T)^{-1})L^Tv.$$

In other words, each solution $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L^{-1}B(L^T)^{-1}$. Since $B$ is symmetric, $L^{-1}B(L^T)^{-1}$ is symmetric as well. The eigenvalues of symmetric matrices are real, hence we have the desired result.

Comment: Yes, that is the theorem in question. Thank you.